# Custom Spring Integration Splitter throwing error

Tags: spring, spring-integration, splitter

Hi I am Trying to extract multiple messages from a single message and split those into multiple messages using a splitter element. But my Splitter is throwing the below error

> 2015-10-26 15:09:06,257 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#1': Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.SplitterFactoryBean#20e2ef61' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.SplitterFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'handlers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.SplitterFactoryBean#20e2ef61': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.String] for method match: [public java.util.List com.salesorder.payment.util.PoslogToIsellRequests.poslogTransformer(java.lang.String), public java.util.List com.salesorder.payment.util.PoslogToIsellRequests.split(java.util.List)]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121)
>       at

The splitter block:

```
<si:splitter>

        <bean
            class="com.ikea.pip.salesorder.payment.util.PoslogToIsellRequests"
            p:mapTaxRateCategory="${common.map.tax.rate.category}" p:buCode="${common.country.code.iso}"
            p:sourceRegion="${common.isell.order.source}" p:countryCode ="${common.country.code.iso}" />
        </si:splitter>
```

Java Code of the class:

```
public class PoslogToIsellRequests implements Splitter {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(PoslogToIsellRequests.class);

private static final String ORDER= "SpecialOrderNumber";
private static XMLInputFactory inputFactory;
private final SimpleXslt transformPoslogXslt = new SimpleXslt(
        "xsl/POSLogToAddPaymentRequest.xsl");
private String sourceRegion;
private String buCode;
private String mapTaxRateCategory;
private String countryCode;
static {

    inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE,
            Boolean.TRUE);

}

public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
    this.countryCode = countryCode;
}
@Override
public List<String> split(List<String> xmlToSplit) {
    List<String> splittedPayload = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String xml : xmlToSplit) {
        splittedPayload.addAll(split(xml));
    }

    return splittedPayload;
}
public void setSourceRegion(String sourceRegion) {
    this.sourceRegion = sourceRegion;
}

public void setBuCode(String buCode) {
    this.buCode = buCode;
}
public void setMapTaxRateCategory(String mapTaxRateCategory) {
    this.mapTaxRateCategory = mapTaxRateCategory;
}
/* @param xmlToSplit
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
public List<String> split(String xmlToSplit) {
    List<String> resultSet=new ArrayList<String>();
    resultSet=poslogTransformer(xmlToSplit);
    return resultSet;
}

public List<String> poslogTransformer(String xmlToSplit) {
    List<String> resultSet=null;
    Set<String> orderNos=new HashSet<String>();
    String payload = xmlToSplit;
    try{
        orderNos= parseOrderNos(payload);

        resultSet=new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        LOG.warn("Could not parse Transaction");

    }
    for(String orderno:orderNos){
        Map<String, String> parameters = createParams(orderno);
    String result = transformPoslogXslt.transform(payload,
            parameters);
    resultSet.add(result);
    }
    return resultSet;
    }
private Map<String, String> createParams(String orderNo) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();


    parameters.put("sourceRegion", sourceRegion);
    parameters.put("buCode",buCode );
    parameters.put("mapTaxRateCategory",mapTaxRateCategory );
    parameters.put("orderNo",orderNo );
    parameters.put("countryCode", countryCode);
    return parameters;
}
private Set<String> parseOrderNos(String payload) throws XMLStreamException {
    Set<String> orders=new HashSet<String>();
    XMLEventReader reader;
    reader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(payload));

    String currentElement = "";

    try {
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();

            if (event.isStartElement()) {

                currentElement = event.asStartElement().getName()
                        .getLocalPart();


            } else if (currentElement.equals(ORDER)
                    && event.isCharacters()) {

                String value = event.asCharacters().getData();
                if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)){
                orders.add(value);}

            }
        }
    } finally {

        reader.close();
    }

    return orders;
}
```

}

The Splitter interface is just contains two split method. Is method overloading not allowed in spring Integration?

One additional query can I have string input as a parameter instead of message?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't explicity identify the method name in the splitter, the framework will detect multiple method candidates and won't be able to determine which one to call.

Hence:

> Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.String] for method match: [public java.util.List com.salesorder.payment.util.PoslogToIsellRequests.poslogTransformer(java.lang.String), public java.util.List com.salesorder.payment.util.PoslogToIsellRequests.split(java.util.List)]

All public methods are considered for POJO method matching unless you specify `method="split"`.

If you add that, the framework will invoke the appropriate `split` method, depending on the payload type of the inbound message.